# Any summation identities which resemble with $\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=1}^m i^j$

Tags: summation, products

I want to compute that $\sum_{i=2}^{n}\dfrac{i^{m+1}-1}{i-1}+m=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=1}^m i^j$. If you closely notice I just rewrote summation of power sum. I tried to search google for any known identity, but I couldn't find anything. Another thing I want to confirm is that $\underbrace{\Pi_{a=1}^n\Pi_{b=1}^a\cdots\Pi_{r=1}^p}_{m \text{ times}}=\dfrac{(n+m-1)!}{n!m!}$. I don't have any proof for this but I found it by fixing some $m$ and running wolfram on this series. If you know any series identities which can simplify these, please let me know.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can note that
$$
\dfrac{i^{m+1}-1}{i-1} = \sum_{j=0}^m i^j
$$

So, your sum is

$$
m+\sum_{i=2}^n \sum_{j=0}^m i^j
$$

Comment: @PierreCarre as I said you can convert this to sum of power sum if u add $m$ back. But I am looking for a formula for this summation.

Comment: @PierreCarre. The problem is $n$

Comment: Statement $\sum_{i=2}^{n}\dfrac{i^{m+1}-1}{i-1}+m=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=1}^m j^i$ is clearly wrong in general case. Then what does mean "compute that $\sum_{i=2}^{n}\dfrac{i^{m+1}-1}{i-1}+m=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=1}^m j^i$"? Or maybe one means $\sum_{i=1}^{m}\dfrac{i^{n+1}-1}{i-1}=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=1}^m j^i$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I meant that both statements are equivalent. You can expand them and see that both are equal.

Comment: I still don't understand what does mean "I want to compute that 74=69". Let take $n=5$, $m=2$. Then $\sum_{i=2}^{n}\dfrac{i^{m+1}-1}{i-1}+m=74$, $\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=1}^m i^j=69$.